# Should we use an Identity server for our core?

Tags: security

We are currently making the codebase for our company.
In this project we upload user data like users ID card, drive license, bills for identity confirmation and a lot of other sensitive data.

My question is why we should use a server that only helps with authentication when we already have to deal with the user data?

From my point of view we are just adding a layer of confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of reasons:

- You can use a tried-and-trusted authentication solution, completely independent of any other code you write.  The authentication server is a prime target for hackers.
- It keeps user authentication separate from your customer service people who are dealing with user data.  Again, it reduces the security risk.